# Using SearchableSpinner with Custom Adapter in Android

Tags: android, spinner, custom-adapter, getview

I am using ‍‍SearchableSpinner in my Android project and in my SearchableSpinner, I am using two textview so I made a custom adapter. When I click the SearchableSpinner, the data not showing properly.

[image: Spinner]

[image: There is no problem is fetching data but when I click it to select any item, the problem will show like that]

Here is my custom adapter code. I use getView and getDropDownview in my custom adapter.

```
private ArrayList<University> universityList;
private Activity context;

public UniversityListAdapterForUploadPage(ArrayList<University> universityList, Activity context){
    super(context,R.layout.university_list_row_for_spinner,universityList);
    this.universityList = universityList;
    this.context = context;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View customView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.university_list_row_for_spinner,null,true);

    TextView universityIDText  = customView.findViewById(R.id.universityID_textView_for_spinner);
    TextView universityNameText = customView.findViewById(R.id.university_name_textView_for_spinner);

    University university = universityList.get(position);

    universityIDText.setText(university.getUniversityID()+"");
    universityNameText.setText(university.getUniversityName());

    return customView;
}

@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View customView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.university_list_row_for_spinner,null,true);

    TextView universityIDText  = customView.findViewById(R.id.universityID_textView_for_spinner);
    TextView universityNameText = customView.findViewById(R.id.university_name_textView_for_spinner);

    University university = universityList.get(position);

    universityIDText.setText(university.getUniversityID()+"");
    universityNameText.setText(university.getUniversityName());

    return customView;
}
```

I need help.

Answer (score 0):

```
universityIDText.setText(university.getUniversityID()+"");
universityNameText.setText(university.getUniversityName());
```

You're not passing a `String` with these two calls. You're passing a java object ID

Comment: Actually I'am passing String value here: university.getUniversityName()

Comment: Yes it is technically a string, But I meant you are passing a string representation of a Java ID, not the String of the value of the Java object

Comment: Okey, I made like this but it didn't work: String universityName = university.getUniversityName(); universityNameText.setText(universityName); Also it's working fine with normal Spinner and ListView

Answer (score 0):

@Override toString() in your Model
Add this to your Model class.. Hope it will help ..

```
public String toString(){
    return universityName;
}
```